# Stability of different tautomers of vitamin C

Tags: biochemistry, stability, tautomer

[image]

Above all four tautomers represent Vitamin C (Ascorbic acid)

So here are some basic rules that I learnt.

1.Usually keto form is more stable due to bond enthalpy considerations

2.Enol form is stable if :

```
  (1)It is aromatic (diamagnetic ring current stabilization)
  (2)It is highly conjugated
  (3)it has 5/6 membered intramolecular hydrogen bonding
  (4)keto has highly acidic alpha-hydrogen
  (5)keto is cyclic 1,2 diketo
  (6)keto is 1,3 dicarbonyl
```

Using these rules I was able to conclude :

- 4th structure is least stable
- 2nd structure is 2nd least stable

But for the 1st and 3rd structures both satisfy 2(3) point given above.

What is the final stability order?

Comment: Only two of structures are tautomers. Other two are oxidized forms.

Comment: @mat not really, oxidised form has three carbonyls. Check how double bond goes from C=C to C=O.

Comment: @OP You're wrong about 3rd structure, enols of carboxyls are much worse, even than ketones.

Comment: @Mithoron why is that?

Comment: one theoretical explanation for comparing and 1st and 3rd structures could be that the carbonyl group of the cylic ester (in structure 1) has an oxygen with higher negative charger density due to inductive and electronic effects, as compared to the oxygen of the carbonyl group in structure 3. This results in stronger hydrogen bonding?